# Precise position of widgets for libGDX scene2d

Tags: android, libgdx, 2d-games, scene2d

I want to layout a set off press-able piano keys in my libGDX app, something like the following:[image: piano key layout]

When a key is pressed, I need to change it from the up to down position (this is easy using an image button).

What I'm struggling with is how to layout all of the buttons such that they for something that resembles a piano keyboard. The white piano key images are rectangular, but a black piano key needs to be placed on top of it. Below shows what one of my white piano key images looks like, there is dead space in the top corner where I intend to put a black note.

[image]

Using a `Table` won't work, as tables layout everything side-by-side, which would leave me with gaps. I've seen you can use a [`Stack`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Stack.html), but that just lays every child directly on top of the last, so that doesn't seem to help either.

If it helps, my code is something like this:

```
Skin skin;
Stage stage;
SpriteBatch batch;
private TextButton button1;
private TextButton button2;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    createSkin();

    Table table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(table);

    // Create a button with the "default" TextButtonStyle. A 3rd parameter can be used to specify a name other than "default".
    button1 = new TextButton("First note", skin);
    button1.getLabel().setFontScale(5);

    button2 = new TextButton("Second note", skin);
    button2.getLabel().setFontScale(5);

    table.add(button1).width(500).height(500);
    table.add(button2).width(500).height(200);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    super.render();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize (int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    stage.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
}

private void createSkin() {
    skin = new Skin();

    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pixmap.fill();
    skin.add("white", new Texture(pixmap));

    skin.add("default", new BitmapFont());

    TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.DARK_GRAY);
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.BLUE);
    textButtonStyle.checked = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.DARK_GRAY);
    textButtonStyle.over = skin.newDrawable("white", Color.DARK_GRAY);
    textButtonStyle.font = skin.getFont("default");
    skin.add("default", textButtonStyle);
}
```

Which renders this:
[image]

There's no way to overlap things as far as I can tell using table, but I can't find another way of doing it. Is doing this possible using scene2d?

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution seems to be to create second **Stage** with same viewport (stages needs to behave in the same way in case of resizing) and place it over your current one. You need to create same table but fullfill it only with black notes (your current stage would contains only white ones of course).

Notice that you will need to use [InputMultiplexer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html) to get event from both stages - you can [read here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling#inputmultiplexer) about how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the Buttons that represent keys to the stage directly without putting them in a Table. Set their positions manually. Should be pretty easy to do manually since piano keys have a clear pattern. Add the black keys after adding the white keys. Then you don't have to worry about the white keys being non-rectangular because the black keys will get prioritized for receiving input.